# Как задать диапазон значений в Edit Text Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Добрый день,
являюсь новичком в программировании , поэтому прошу не ругать сильно в случае чего.
Делаю небольшое приложение для рабочих нужд - суть приложения в том, чтобы высчитывать визовые коридоры.Столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Есть поле EditText для дня месяца, и хотелось бы либо ограничить диапазон значений в зависимости от месяца от 1 до 31, либо ,в лучае если введено значение больше возможного - то чтоб значение поля сбросилось на дефолтное.

Хотелось бы чтоб значение менялось ,когда пропадает фокус с данного EditText.
Попробовал сделать так

```
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {


    if (!view.hasFocus()){
        if (monthId == 2 && Integer.parseInt(day.getText().toString())>28){
            day.setText("28");
        }else if (monthId == 4 || monthId == 5 || monthId == 9 || monthId ==11 &&
                Integer.parseInt(day.getText().toString())>30){
            day.setText("30");
        }
    }else if (Integer.parseInt(day.getText().toString())>31){
        day.setText("31");
    }


}
```

Но не могу понять в каком методе надо создать слушателя, ведь ,как я понимаю, алгоритм такой -
поле получает фокус - происходят изменения - поле теряет фокус ( выполняется код). 
Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так (где `15` – значение по умолчанию):

```
mEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus) {
                    int day;
                    try {
                        day = Integer.parseInt(mEditText.getText().toString());
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        mEditText.setText("15");
                        return;
                    }

                    if (day < 1 || day > 31) {
                        mEditText.setText("15");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

В дополнении напишу, что также можно осуществить проверку «на лету»:

```
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        int day;
        try {
            day = Integer.parseInt(mEditText.getText().toString());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            mEditText.setText("15");
            return;
        }

        if (day < 1 || day > 31) {
            mEditText.setText("15");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, особенно с проверкой "на лету". Очень помогло!